# How do I use the output of swagger-jaxrs-doclet to generate swagger documentation?

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I'm very new to [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/) so I may have some of these details wrong.  Swagger seems like a cool tool for generating REST documentation.  But, I don't like that it's very invasive and requires me to put annotations on my java classes.  I found this maven plugin named [swagger-jaxrs-doclet](https://github.com/ryankennedy/swagger-jaxrs-doclet) that seems to generate these json files that I should be able to pass into swagger to generate the swagger documentation.  The advantage is I don't need to put swagger annotations on any of my classes.

Unfortunately the swagger-jaxrs-doclet documentation doesn't tell me what to do next.  Can someone show me how to take the output of swagger-jaxrs-doclet and generate swagger documentation from it?  I need to do this in maven.

Comment: --> Daniel : Were you able to get an solution to this because I too exactly need the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just upload the apidocs or the dist folder (Based on which swagger-ui version you are using) on some local server and open from your browser. The javascript gets executed and you will see the output.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "Usage section" on https://github.com/teamcarma/swagger-jaxrs-doclet - for examples for both maven and gradle.

Also, the "Example" section seems pretty straight forward; hence a bit un-sure what it is that you are looking for help with. If you could be a little more - " Can someone show me how to take the output of swagger-jaxrs-doclet and generate swagger documentation from it? I need to do this in maven."

As I understand the com.carma:swagger-doclet generates the necessary Swagger 1.2 resource description files and places them in the "build/reports/rest-api-docs" if you just use their example as is.

Answer (score 0):

The way I set it up for my java project using gradle was the following:

1). Add a doclet configuration to build.grade

```
doclet(
      [group: 'com.carma', name: 'swagger-doclet', version: '1.0.4.2'],
      [group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0']
```

)

2). Create a gradle task to generate the rest docs after the build
    task generateRestApiDocs(type: Javadoc) {

```
source = sourceSets.main.allJava
  def file = new File(project.rootDir.toString() + "/my-app/src/main/resources/assets/api-docs")

  destinationDir = file
  options.classpath = configurations.doclet.files.asType(List)
  options.docletpath = configurations.doclet.files.asType(List)
  options.doclet = "com.carma.swagger.doclet.ServiceDoclet"
  options.addStringOption("apiVersion", "1")
  options.addStringOption("docBasePath", "/assets/api-docs")
  options.addStringOption("apiBasePath", "../../")
  options.addBooleanOption("skipUiFiles", true)
  if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none')
  }
 }
```

3). Make build depend on the generated rest docs task

```
build.dependsOn generateRestApiDocs
```

4).  Annotate and javadoc your resources

```
/**
   * Endpoint to do something blah blah
   *
   * @param id blah blah blah
   * @param boolean blah blah blahb
   * @return {@link blab}
   * @responseMessage 200 ok
   * @responseMessage 404 not found
   */
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("/{id}")
```

5).  The build task will create the necessary swagger json files to be served out by your swagger ui.

Comment: This'll probably be helpful for others, but like I said I'm using maven, not gradle.

Comment: I am struggling to get this to work with Gradle. I am building a REST server with Dropwizard and have not been successful with the swagger automated documentation. I have followed this link https://itazuramono.com/2015/12/07/automatic-swagger-documentation-for-dropwizard-using-maven/ but with the Gradle version from https://github.com/conorroche/swagger-doclet and still get a 404 from jetty. Do you have an example project you could share? Or at least show what your build directory looks like? My build directory has the apidocs but the swagger ui was not included. Help?